# retrieve data from a list of specific IDs in Firebase, follow user and only get their posts

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, redux

I have a list of users and they can each post events and follow each other, and when they do, the database will generate a `feed` object with `userId` object and a list of events they can see, like this:

[image]

`Mo4JxyP4FCRtXYtNZAqs4EsLtTh2` and `tq3bugOm5pRE2PxpmllKzUhKjty1` are User IDs, and `-KIMxxx: true` are the event posts.

In a separate `events` object, I have the details of the event stored there:[image]

Currently, I retrieve all events in redux like this:

```
export const eventsFetch = () => {
  return (dispatch) => {
    firebase.database().ref(`/events/`)
      .on('value', snapshot => {
        dispatch({ type: EVENTS_FETCH_SUCCESS, payload: snapshot.val() });
      });
  };
};
```

How can I rewrite the method so it only retrieves data from the list of event IDs under a user's ID? I tried to do

```
firebase.database().ref(`/feed/${this.auth.currentUser.uid}`)
```

to get the object first, then use `Object.keys()` to get an array like so `["eventId1", "eventId2"]`, but now I'm stuck and not sure how to loop through all

```
firebase.database().ref(`/events/${eventId}`)
```

and dispatch all the data together like the mehtod above shown... not sure if I want to use `.once('value)` as I'd like to keep the list of events updated as the user unfollow/follow.

Bonus request, if it's possible, as you can see in `events/${eventId}/timeAsDate`, each event have a time,  I'd like to hide/not retrieve events that is in the past.

Thanks

**UPDATE**
thanks to Frank's answer, I finally got it working with the following code:

```
export const eventsFetch = () => {
  const { currentUser } = firebase.auth();

  return (dispatch) => {
    firebase.database().ref(`/feed/${currentUser.uid}`).on('value', snapshots => {
      const values = snapshots.val() || {};
      const entryIds = Object.keys(values);
      const promises = entryIds.map(
        eventId => firebase.database().ref(`/events/${eventId}`).once('value')
      );

      Promise.all(promises).then(results => {
        results.forEach(result => {
          values[result.key] = result.val();
        });
        dispatch({ type: EVENTS_FETCH_SUCCESS, payload: values });
      });
    });
  };
};
```

Answer (score 3):

Something like this should do the trick:

```
export const eventsFetchForUser = (uid) => {
  return (dispatch) => {
    firebase.database().ref(`/feed/${uid}`)
      .on('value', snapshot => {
        var promises = [];
        snapshots.forEach((key) => {
          promises.push(
            firebase.database().ref(`/events/${key.key}`)).once('value')
          );
        });
        Promise.all(promises).then((snapshots) => {
          const values = snapshots.map(snapshot => snapshot.val));
          dispatch({ type: EVENTS_FETCH_SUCCESS, payload: values });
        });
      });
  };
};
```

So this first loads the keys from the user's feed, then loads each post by its key, and finally extracts the value of each post's snapshot before dispatching it all.

*Note: I didn't run this, so typos are likely.*

Comment: Your `Promise.all` call won't resolve correctly - you need to go `Promise.all(promises).then((snapshots) => { //Results here })`

Comment: Woops. Good one. Thanks for catching. Fixed.

Comment: hi @FrankvanPuffelen thank u so much for helping out another Firebase question! I got it working and updated my question. Also, if I want to sort the events by time, and not show past events, should I handle that logic in this method or maybe do it in another method before or after? Thanks again

Comment: It sounds like something that would fit fine in this method. But I'd update the user's feed to in that case have the timestamp as a value (instead of just `true`), so that you can limit the number of items on the feed already.